# Asp.net adding table from code behind does not work as expected

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I am trying to dynamically add tables in my page. I have a placeholder in aspx page and add my tables to that placeholder. Here is my code:

```
foreach (String blockName in intersectedBlocks)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable subjects = new DataTable();

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [coursename], [coursesection] FROM academicblocks where blockname=@blockname", CommonFunctions.con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@blockname", blockName);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);

                Table t = new Table();
                t.BorderWidth = 5;

                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                TableCell cl = new TableCell();
                cl.Text = blockName;
                row.Cells.Add(cl);
                t.Rows.Add(row);




                foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
                {
                    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                    TableCell c = new TableCell();
                    c.Text = r["coursename"] + " " + r["coursesection"];
                    tr.Cells.Add(c);
                     t.Rows.Add(tr);
                }

                placeholder.Controls.Add(t);


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                CommonFunctions.con.Close();
            }
            index++;
            CommonFunctions.con.Close();

        }
```

That works fine, tables are added. The problem is, second table is added below the first table, and 3rd is added below 2nd table. But i want them to be added side by side. Here is how it looks like: I do not want them to be added below.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: that basicly how tables are layed, by defaut they are block elements, you may use `table{display:inline-table;}` to have them act like `inline-block` elements and stand side by side , or `float` them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you better to make one main Table with one TR and many TDs in that TR. 
Then just add table for each TD in that one TR